# How should i start transforming my JS poker app into an MVC one?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I've been developing a multiplayer poker app that contains a table with seats, chat box, top panel (buttons, game options) and bottom panel (buttons, player actions during a turn).

Up until now, 99% of the project is a single main "Game" object that contains ALL the methods.
Now, i want to transform my app into an MVC one, but **i'm new to the concept** and i'm not sure how many controllers/models/views should i have.

Is it "normal" to have only a single controller, model and view? (client side)
If not, what could be a better approach?

Thanks in advance.

*Try not to reply with URLs, i only want some general guidelines relevant to my project.

Answer (score 0):

It's excellent you're developing a poker app. I consider it's OK to have only a single controller, model and view at the beginning. I wish you good luck, and you have to share the results. I'd like to have a try. In the future, you could take a look here https://pokerace7.com/. Maybe some things would inspire you. If you'd need additional help, I could get you in touch with my cousin Sam. He's totally into coding and developing games, and for a symbolic price, I guess he might help you correct the errors and go further.